# Must the array always be sorted before using it to create a binary search tree? If so, what's the reason?

Tags: c++, sorting, binary-search-tree

What is the reason that the following implementation for creating a binary search tree does not result in a sorted list after in-order traversal.

```
void binarySearchTree(node* &head, int array[], int i, int size){
    if(i >= size){
        return;
    }
    head = new node;
    head->left = NULL;
    head->right = NULL;
    head->data = array[i];
    if(array[++i] <= head->data){
        binarySearchTree(head->left, array, i, size);
    }
    else{
        binarySearchTree(head->right, array, i, size);
    }
}
```

The array I passed to this function is as follows:

```
int array[] = {10,9,8,7,101,5,4,3,2,1};
```

Once I sort the array and then pass it to the function, the resultant list after in-order traversal is sorted.
I don't understand the reason.

Can someone please help me understand it?

Must the array always be sorted before passing it to the function? If so, what is the reason?

Comment: Yes, my bad. I edited it.

Comment: And assuming that `size` is the number of elements in the array, then you will go out of bounds of the array.

Comment: In general, passing elements of a sorted array in order to a trivial BST.AddNode function will cause a lop-sided tree, but it will still be a valid BST.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, do you mean something like this:            
   `if(array[i] <= head->data){
        binarySearchTree(head->left, array, ++i, size);
    }
    else{
        binarySearchTree(head->right, array, ++i, size);
    }`

Comment: @s.tiss Don't write `++i` when you can use `i+1`. That side effect has caused countless hard-to-find bugs through the years.

Comment: Once you've established that 9 goes in the left subtree of the root 10, all nodes are added to the left subtree of the root; its right subtree is empty. (Since every node has exactly one child, your "tree" is a linked list which uses a different "next" pointer depending on whether the next value is smaller or not. It zig-zags, but doesn't branch.)

Comment: @molbdnilo, can you please fix it...

Comment: @s.tiss No, I don't think so, but note that your "successful" version with a sorted array is also, in effect, a linked list - every node has a right child and no left child - so your lookup time is the worst possible (linear). You need to interpret the array as an inorder tree in that case. (You can't get around either sorting the array or writing a "proper" tree insertion function. It's impossible to build a BST from arbitrary inputs in linear time.)

Answer (score 0):

> Must the array always be sorted before using it to create a binary search tree?

No, such restriction is not needed. It is possible to create a binary search tree without sorting the input array.

> What is the reason that the following implementation for creating a binary search tree does not result in a sorted list after in-order traversal.

Because it's broken. You always insert next element as a child of previous element. This won't work when the correct place for the node is neither of those children. Perhaps it's easier to see with a simpler example. With input of 2,1,3 the resulting tree is:

```
   2
  /
 /
1
 \
  3
```

3 does not belong to the left side of 2, and therefore it shouldn't be a child of 1.

A correct way to implement it is to start the search from the root for every element. A structured way to implement it is to implement insertion for single element, and use that in a loop to insert many.

---

Note however that if the tree insertion is extended to support hints, then the complexity of creating from a sorted array is O(N) while complexity of creating from unsorted array is O(N log N).

Also note that if you don't balance the tree, then creating a binary tree from sorted array results in a lopsided tree that has the same structure as a linked list; all nodes being the right child of their predecessor.

Answer (score 0):

> *Must the array always be sorted before passing it to the function?*

No, it does not need to be sorted, corrections in your code are needed, as stated in the comments.

In fact if it is sorted, in the end you will have a completely unbalanced tree, it will have basically the characteristics of a linked list. So if you want a propper BST I would advise the use of rebalancing algorithms, a self-balancing AVL tree, or a Red Black tree would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Like others already pointed out above, that recursive function generates not really a tree, but some sort of linked list, because it always adds only one of the leaves, on the left or right side. - Instead, an insert function should traverse the tree and look for the right spot, where to add a new value. That way, you can populate it with new nodes and add the elements of the initial array to the BST data structure one by one, instead of passing the whole array... it's easier that way, I think.

Here a [very crude example](https://onlinegdb.com/bESQ1NbjB). You can find lots of details and further explanations on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree).

```
/*
  $ g++ bst_test.c && ./a.out
  ARRAY: 10 9 8 7 101 5 4 3 2 1                                                                                                                                                                                    
  BST: 1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 10 101 
*/

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    node *left, *right;
    int data;
};

void binarySearchTree_insert(node* &n, int value)
{
    if (n == NULL) {
        n = new node;
        n->left = NULL;
        n->right = NULL;
        n->data = value;
    } else if (value <= n->data) {
        binarySearchTree_insert(n->left, value);
    } else if (value > n->data) {
        binarySearchTree_insert(n->right, value);
    }
}

void binarySearchTree_print(node *n)
{
    if (n == NULL)
        return;
    binarySearchTree_print(n->left);
    cout << n->data << " ";
    binarySearchTree_print(n->right);
}

int main()
{
    const int array[] = {10,9,8,7,101,5,4,3,2,1};
    node *bst = NULL;
    
    cout << "ARRAY: ";
    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]); ++i) {
        cout << array[i] << " ";
        binarySearchTree_insert(bst, array[i]); 
    }
    cout << endl;
    
    cout << "BST: ";
    binarySearchTree_print(bst);
    cout << endl;

    /* TODO: cleanup! -> delete all nodes here */
    return 0;
}
```